# flex sensors with arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a **flex sensor** connected with an **arduino lily pad** and an `47k ohms` resistor.

My problem is that I am unable to get the consistent values from **flex sensors**: sometimes, *i get very strange readings, even though the flex sensor is not in bending state*.

I tried to change the values of `straight_resistance` and `bend_resistance`, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Here is my code, looking forward for help.

```cpp
const int FLEX_PIN = A0; // Pin connected to voltage divider output

// Measure the voltage at 5V and the actual resistance of your
// 47k resistor, and enter them below:
const float VCC = 4.98; // Measured voltage of Ardunio 5V line (r1/r1+r2)5
const float R_DIV = 47500.0; // Measured resistance of 3.3k resistor

// Upload the code, then try to adjust these values to more
// accurately calculate bend degree.
const float STRAIGHT_RESISTANCE = 24248750.00; // resistance when     straight 
const float BEND_RESISTANCE = 48544996.00; // resistance at 90 deg

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(FLEX_PIN, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  // Read the ADC, and calculate voltage and resistance from it
  int flexADC = analogRead(FLEX_PIN);
  float flexV = flexADC * VCC / 1023.0;
  float flexR = R_DIV * (VCC / flexV - 1.0);
  Serial.println("Resistance: " + String(flexR) + " ohms");

  // Use the calculated resistance to estimate the sensor's
  // bend angle:
  float angle = map(flexR, STRAIGHT_RESISTANCE, BEND_RESISTANCE,
               0, 90.0);
  Serial.println("Bend: " + String(angle) + " degrees");
  Serial.println();

  delay(750);
}
```

Comment: did you check whether your flex sensor is not broken? You could try using an ohmmeter to check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following values from your code don't seem right.  These are values in the MOhms, not kOhms.

```
const float STRAIGHT_RESISTANCE = 24248750.00; // resistance when     straight 
const float BEND_RESISTANCE = 48544996.00; // resistance at 90 deg
```

Another problem is the map() function only works with integers!  The floating point values you are passing in are converted to integers before the map() function uses them.